# delete images through database and directory

Tags: php, html, mysql

can somebody help me for my codes. i can delete the image in the database but in the directory i can't. im tried for long hours but it seems not work at all. would somebody help me please?          here's my code:     this is the code where the images

```
<?
//this is were images displayed
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category='home'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    ?>
                    <a href="edithomephotos.php?delete=<?=$row['imageID']?>" onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"><img src="images/template/delete.png" id="AEDbutton"></a>


                    echo "<img border=\"0\" src=\"".$row['image']."\" width=\"200\"  height=\"100\">";
                    echo "<br>";                }   


?>
```

,?

```
include('global.php');

//this is were image were deleted

if($delete != "") 



    {

        $query = "DELETE FROM images WHERE imageID='".$delete."'";
        ExecuteQuery($query);   

}

//but in here , it cannot delete image through directory
           $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE imageID='".$delete."'";

                $result = mysql_query($query);

while ($delete = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $image = $delete['image'];

                 $file= '/.directory/'.$image;

                        unlink($file);


    }



?>
```

Comment: you should replace at first $delete with $_REQUEST['delete']

Comment: You do realize you execute a `SELECT` statement AFTER you've `DELETE`d the record?

Comment: This is exactly why I use galleryproject [http://galleryproject.org/gallery_3_begins] for my backend stuff

Comment: yeah , i do have request . ive changed it now a while ago, but the error is this "Warning: unlink(../directory/directory/33.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\updatedTHESIS\updatedILAMadmin\edithomephotos.php on line 27" and i dnt know why

Answer (score 2):

You already deleted the image entry in table, after that you try to get the same entry in DB. so, first you can delete the image from folder after that you can delete in the table.

```
<?php
    include('global.php');

    if($delete != "") {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE imageID='".$delete."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        while ($delete = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $image = $delete['image'];
            $file= '/.directory/'.$image;
            unlink($file);
        }

        $query = "DELETE FROM images WHERE imageID='".$delete."'";
        ExecuteQuery($query);   
    }
?>
```

**Note:**
Make sure your path `$file= '/.directory/'.$image;` is correct, I think it referring from root directory.

Comment: i tried this " $file= "../directory/".$image.;" but nothing seems working at all. and the error was this :
Warning: unlink(/.directory/directory/33.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\updatedTHESIS\updatedILAMadmin\edithomephotos.php on line 27

Comment: Make sure you point it to the right folder. You probably don't need to add `'/.directory/'` to the `$file`-variable.
Try using only `unlink($file);` and see what you get.
If your images are stored in a specific folder, let's say '/images/' inside your current working directory, you can use `unlink('images/'.$image)`.

Answer (score 1):

Funny. That's because you are first deleting the image id from the database and after that you are trying to get the ID of the previously deleted image (which no longer exists) and delete the file associated with it. Switch the code like this.

```
include('global.php');

if($delete != "") 
{
//first delete the file
$query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE imageID='".$delete."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($delete = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    try
    {
        $image = $delete['image'];
        $file= '/images/'.$image;
        unlink($file);
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}

// after that delete the id from the db of that image associated with the deleted file
$query = "DELETE FROM images WHERE imageID='".$delete."'";
ExecuteQuery($query);   
}
```

UPDATE: I added a try catch

Comment: i tried it that before but it was error.
the error is Warning: unlink(/.directory/directory/33.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\updatedTHESIS\updatedILAMadmin\edithomephotos.php on line 27

Comment: That means the image 33.jpg you are trying to delete does not exist, i'll update the code

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting images, first you need to delete image and then delete in DB